# File not created by a python script that runs on boot

Tags: python, files

I have scripted two python codes. one, to run on boot and to create a file locally in the same directory where the code is placed another one to sense a low to high signal in GPIO. I have placed the code at /etc/rc.local. I'm trying something like this.

```
sleep 1; python /home/ubuntu/Desktop/lcd.py &
sleep 1; python /home/ubuntu/Desktop/button.py
exit 0
```

Both the codes , runs on boot and no issue with that. The problem I'm facing is that the first code " lcd.py" should create a local file and THE FILE HAS NOT BEEN CREATED. I have searched for the existence of file in both the /etc directory and the path of the python script. Can someone help me fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scripts in `/etc/rc.local` run in `/` afaik. You should change the working directory or provide an absolute path in your python script.

Comment: I could not get You as I'm new to linux. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Every process has a _working directory_ (pwd) it 'runs in'. If you do something like `open("path/foobar", "w")` in python it will interpret `path/foobar` **relative to** this working directory. Commands that are executed from `/etc/rc.local` are running in the root directory `/` so your file will end up in `/` if you do not specify an absolute path starting with `/` like `/path/to/file`. In a shell you can change the working directory with the `cd` command, in python with `os.chdir(dirname)`.